# Chrome closes the tooltip dialog box immediately when firing server side validation

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

The extlib tooltip dialog box work fine on IE and Firefox but but not Chrome.  When the tooltip dialog box is opened, click on Save button without entering any values to any mandatory fields, it expects the error message list being displayed.  However, Chrome closes it immediately.  Any ideas how to stop it?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: <xp:link escape="true"
    text="Create a new WN Blueprint"
    id="lnkNewApplicationProfile" style="font-weight:bold">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
     refreshMode="norefresh"
     onComplete="XSP.openTooltipDialog('#{id:ttdlgApplicationProfile}','#{id:lnkNewApplicationProfile}')">
     <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.ApplicationProfileDocId
//viewScope.ApplicationProfileDocId = "";}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
   </xp:link>

Comment: Here as above.  It is working on latest IE and firefox but not Chrome.  Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: I was not able to replicate the problem. What version of Domino are you running?